# Create a visual template for grid

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I am trying to create a visual template (saved in resource dictionary as xaml code) for a `grid` object, that I will apply to various `grid` objects created later in runtime.

I need a simple style with border and background.
What would be the best way of doing this?

Simple working examples would be greatly appreciated.

Ok, so, after searching for examples, I tried something like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

<Style x:Key="TestStyle">
<Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF873507" />
<Setter.Value>
    <ControlTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <Border BorderThickness="7" CornerRadius="4">
                <Border.BorderBrush>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#73B2F5"/>
                </Border.BorderBrush>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Setter.Value>
</Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPF doesn't really work like that... because the `Grid` class has no `Template` property, you cannot define a new `ControlTemplate` for it. The nearest thing that you can do is to create a `UserControl` with the UI elements that you want to use and then display the `UserControl` wherever you want to display those controls.

Alternatively, you *could* define your content inside a `ControlTemplate` if the inner controls will always be the same:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="StaticGrid">
    <Grid>
        <Border BorderThickness="7" CornerRadius="4">
            <Border.BorderBrush>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="#73B2F5"/>
            </Border.BorderBrush>
            <!--Add your inner elements here-->
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

You could then display it like this:

```
<ContentControl Template="{StaticResource StaticGrid}" />
```

However, you wouldn't be able to add different inner elements using this method. If you used the `UserControl` method, you could potentially replace the word `UserControl` with `Grid` so that you were in fact extending the `Grid` class, but you still wouldn't be able to add different elements to it.

The best that you could do in a `Style` would be to set the `Background` property.

Comment: Thank You! This works. Is there a way to change the applied `ControlTemplate` to a different `ControlTemplate` later using code?

Comment: Sure. See the [Change Templates Dynamically in WPF](http://weblogs.asp.net/psheriff/change-templates-dynamically-in-wpf) page on Paul Sheriff's Blog for the Real World for an example... bear in mind that that is actually for `DataTemplate`s, but the process is the same for `ControlTemplate`s and the `Template` property. Search online for further help.

Answer (score 0):

After more tries and frustrations, I found a much simpler solution, that worked for me.
Instead of trying to apply the style to the grid, I applied it to the border around the grid.

So, my dictionary looks like this:

```
<Style x:Key="TestStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Border}">

    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFBDACA2" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FFFF5E00" />
    <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="30,30,30,30" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="10" />

</Style>
```

And my main frame xaml:

```
<Border Style="{StaticResource TestStyle}" >
    <Grid>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```